# Visualize jQuery plugin not working in IE8, FF and Safari

Tags: jquery, jsp, firefox, internet-explorer-8, safari

I am trying to use jQuery visualize plugin in order to generate graph from tables in a jsp. I am appending the graph to a div tag.
This is working fine in IE9 and IE7(In IE7 bit distorted).
In IE8, firefox and Safari only the box comes but it doesn't have the graph within it.

Could you please help me on this.
Thanking you for your help.

Comment: One more thing if I am trying to append it in body its working, but if I try it adding to a particular div id its not working
Also its not working in default way,i.e. without appending to a specific location.

Answer (score 0):

First create the graphic, and then append it to its container element, using the class selector:

```
$("table").visualize()
        .appendTo("body")
        .trigger('visualizeRefresh');
$("div").append($(".visualize"));
```

I hope that works.